# First selected row in selection: ActiveCell.row behaviour

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I'm trying to determine the first selected row within a selection.

My attempt with **ActiveCell.row** fails due to different behaviour if selection is
made by pressing
(1) SHIFT + selection or
(2) CTRL + selection.

With (1) **ActiveCell.row** shows the first selected row
With (2) **ActiveCell.row** shows the last selected row

Any idea how I can get the first selected row no matter how the user does the selection?

Comment: The active cell is the one that is clear while the others are shaded.  It is different than `Selection.Row` which  will default to the top most.  Ctrl remembers the previous selection but activates the last.  While shift selects from the active to the next click leaving the first as active. ActiveCell can only be one cell, while Selection can be multiple.  The ActiveCell is contained in the Selected cells, but can be anywhere in that selection.

Comment: I tried **selection.row**. It gives the correct row for almost all selections. It does not give the first selected row if the selection is made with SHIFT + selection with the last selected row is above the first selected row.

Comment: This might be an XY Problem.  What are you trying to accomplish here more broadly?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
Dim firstRow as Range
Set firstRow = Selection.cells(1,1).EntireRow
Debug.Print firstRow.Address
```

Comment: I tried. This gives the same result as selection.row (see above comment)

Comment: @MuratG if you select say `B5:C10` and run the above, what does the Immediate Window output?

Comment: selecting `B5:C10` gives following result: Selection.row: 5
ActiveCell.row: 5
Selection.cells(1,1).EntireRow.Row: 5

Comment: Selecting `C10:B5`gives the following result: Selection.row: 5, 
ActiveCell.row: 10, 
Selection.cells(1,1).EntireRow.Row: 5

Comment: @MuratG is that not correct? The first row in both selections is `5`.

Comment: When I select `B5:C10`I'm trying to get Row 5 as a result. When I select `C10:B5`, I'm trying to get Row 10 as a result. So in other others, determine the row which was clicked first to do the selection

Comment: @MuratG ohhh I see what you mean. Hm, I don't know if that's possible without some tricky vba stuff.  What's the overall point in doing that? Perhaps there's another way to tackle the problem

Comment: I'd like to create dependencies between elements, where the first selected element is dependent to all other selected elements.

Comment: @MuratG what if the macro promoted the user for two ranges. The first would be a single cell that you base dependencies on, the second range being the range for dependencies?